# No maven in intellij idea

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have one project open in IntelliJ. In that I am able to see maven tab in its left sidebar:
[image: maven tab in sidebar]
Also, I am able to see Maven in `View > Tool Windows > Maven`:
[image: View > Tool Windows > Maven]

I tried to open another project in another IntelliJ window, but it does not have both of the above:
[image: no maven tab in sidebar]
[image: no Maven option in View > Tool Windows]

Comment: Make sure you import that other project as a Maven project. You can try the 'File > Open' menu option and choose your project's pom.xml as a source to import it from.

Comment: Or also look at the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html) of Intellij for Maven

Comment: did you create a new configuration in the top nav bar in order to click on the debug/start icon on the bar?

Answer (score -1):

It may be not required to have that maven tool window for the project that you have opened in the second Idea instance.

If the opened project is a maven project (at least if you have a pom.xml associated with that project) you will have this option available in `View -> Tool Windows -> maven`

If it's a maven project, try importing the project as a maven project as well